# How to access last inserted id in PDO with static variable?

Tags: php, pdo

Below is my code.I want to access the last inserted id. Since I use static connection variable , it gives me error accesssing it in this way:
 `$insertedId = $stmt->connection::$pdo->lastInsertId() ;`

```
public function addCar()
    {
        $this->rate=$param6;
        if(!empty($this->name))
        {
        $sql="INSERT INTO car(car_name,car_maker,car_type,car_colour,num_passanger)VALUES('{$this->name}','{$this->maker}', '{$this->type}','{$this->colour}','{$this->passanger}')";
        $stmt =connection::$pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        echo "inserted id ".$insertedId = $stmt->lastInsertId() ;
        }
        //$this->rentalRate();
    }
```

Comment: `$stmt =connection::$pdo->prepare($sql);` Does that even work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Simple way to use the `lastInsertId()` is:

```
// your connection with database
$con = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);

// insert query
$query = "INSERT INTO tbl_name SET col_name1 = ?, col_name2 = ?";
// '$con' is your PDO connection variable
$stmt = $con->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(1, $variable1); // value for col_name1 to be stored
$stmt->bindParam(2, $variable2); // value for col_name2 to be stored
$stmt->execute();
....
// gives current inserted id 
$lastId = $con->lastInsertId();
```

In your case try: `$lastId = connection::$pdo->lastInsertId();`

Comment: I get error: Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::lastInsertedId() in C:\wamp\www\carRental\index.php on line 72

Comment: It is `insert`, not `inserted` So correct method is `lastInsertId()`

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky, thanks for correction dude. I will update.